# How to change color in RGB format in FTGL OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, ftgl

How to change color in RGB format in FTGL OpenGL?

```
FTGLPixmapFont font("arial.ttf");
FTPoint coord(100, 100, 0);
font.FaceSize(20);
font.Render("abc", -1 , coord);
```

Standart color change does not work.

```
glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
FTGLPixmapFont font("arial.ttf");
FTPoint coord(100, 100, 0);

glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
font.FaceSize(20);
font.Render("abc", -1 , coord);

glPopAttrib();
```

Comment: @gotostereo ohh, I see the problem: Use FTGLTextureFont instead of FTGLPixmapFont

Comment: Please write a simple example of how to display text on the screen through FTGLPixmapFont, on the same principle did not work.

Comment: @gotostereo see this here if you want to get it working with FTGLPixmapFont: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/503844-ftgl-color-issues/